# Parsing complex JSON

Tags: javascript, json

My json response:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"SPATIAL_VIEW.fid-54038ee6_13f98ee9f52_4049","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[7.2970943E7,-4.69048595E8]]]},"geometry_name":"GEOM","properties":{"ID":"123","GIS_CODE":"AP","NAME":"Andhra Pradesh"}}],"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"42106"}}}
```

In this I want to get the GIS_CODE as an alert.

What I tried is:
That json response is in "jsoncontent"

```
   var content = eval('('+jsoncontent+')');
   alert(content.features.properties.GIS_CODE);
```

I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'GIS_CODE' of undefined

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

- Firstly you should avoid the usage of `eval`. It is better to use `JSON.parse()` to parse JSON Data into objects.
- Secondly, `features` is an array. You need to use `[]` notation to get the object from it.

After that you should be able to access the values. I can use the following code:

```
var dt=JSON.parse(jsoncontent);
var value=dt.features[0].properties.GIS_CODE;
alert(value);
```